# Gitlab - Clicking on "branches" from within a project returns a 404

Tags: gitlab

I'm relatively new at administering GitLab and I inherited about a dozen instances that host git repos.   I'm hearing complains that clicking on "branches" from within a project will throw a 404.  Looks like it throws a 500 in production.log.  It's only on some projects though.  Other projects behave fine, but I'm not able to find a pattern as to why it happens on some and not on others.  As far as I can see we don't have branches with "#" in the name or two "/".

From nginx access logs:

```
129.46.71.24 - - [31/Oct/2013:14:18:49 -0700] "GET /thirdparty/llvm-static-
artifacts/branches HTTP/1.1" 404 249 "https://gitlab.someurl.com/thirdparty/llvm-
static-artifacts/branches" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36"

129.46.71.24 - - [31/Oct/2013:14:18:49 -0700] "GET /thirdparty/llvm-static-
artifacts/branches HTTP/1.1" 404 249 "https://gitlab.someurl.com/thirdparty/llvm-
static-artifacts/branches" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36"
```

from production.log:

```
Started GET "/thirdparty/llvm-static-artifacts/branches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-31 
14:19:58 -0700
Processing by Projects::BranchesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"thirdparty/llvm-static-artifacts"}
  Rendered shared/_ref_switcher.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered projects/commits/_head.html.haml (4.5ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_filter.html.haml (1.6ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_branch.html.haml (4.3ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_branch.html.haml (2.3ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/index.html.haml within layouts/projects (13.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"destroy",   
:controller=>"projects/branches", :project_id=>#<Project id: 107, name:    
"llvm.static.artifacts", path: "llvm-static-artifacts", description: "", created_at: 
"2013-09-23 21:15:36", updated_at: "2013-10-07 21:56:28", creator_id: 7, default_branch: 
"feature/NEO-10669_clang_and_static_libcxx", issues_enabled: true, wall_enabled: false, 
merge_requests_enabled: true, wiki_enabled: true, namespace_id: 18, public: false, 
issues_tracker: "gitlab", issues_tracker_id: nil, snippets_enabled: false, 
last_activity_at: "2013-10-07 21:56:30", imported: false, import_url: "">, 
:id=>"feature/NEO-5388_update_nst_to_compile_with_llvm/clang32"}):
  app/views/projects/branches/_branch.html.haml:17:in  
`_app_views_projects_branches__branch_html_haml___758623504167079734_70006805062880'

  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:9:in `block in 
_app_views_projects_branches_index_html_haml___1230313324773652987_70006835956360'
  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:8:in `each'
  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:8:in  
`_app_views_projects_branches_index_html_haml___1230313324773652987_70006835956360'


Started GET "/thirdparty/llvm-static-artifacts/branches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-31  
14:19:58 -0700
Processing by Projects::BranchesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"thirdparty/llvm-static-artifacts"}
  Rendered shared/_ref_switcher.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered projects/commits/_head.html.haml (4.4ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_filter.html.haml (1.6ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_branch.html.haml (4.2ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/_branch.html.haml (2.3ms)
  Rendered projects/branches/index.html.haml within layouts/projects (13.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 84ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"destroy",  
:controller=>"projects/branches", :project_id=>#<Project id: 107, name:  
"llvm.static.artifacts", path: "llvm-static-artifacts", description: "", created_at:  
"2013-09-23 21:15:36", updated_at: "2013-10-07 21:56:28", creator_id: 7, default_branch: 
"feature/NEO-10669_clang_and_static_libcxx", issues_enabled: true, wall_enabled: false,  
merge_requests_enabled: true, wiki_enabled: true, namespace_id: 18, public: false, 
issues_tracker: "gitlab", issues_tracker_id: nil, snippets_enabled: false, 
last_activity_at: "2013-10-07 21:56:30", imported: false, import_url: "">, 
:id=>"feature/NEO-5388_update_nst_to_compile_with_llvm/clang32"}):
  app/views/projects/branches/_branch.html.haml:17:in  
`_app_views_projects_branches__branch_html_haml___758623504167079734_70006805062880'
  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:9:in `block in   
_app_views_projects_branches_index_html_haml___1230313324773652987_70006835206340'
  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:8:in `each'
  app/views/projects/branches/index.html.haml:8:in  
`_app_views_projects_branches_index_html_haml___1230313324773652987_70006835206340'
```

Here's what we're running:

```
$ cat VERSION 
6.0.0-ee

$ git branch
  6-0-stable
* master

$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I realize that it says we're behind by 1 commit.   Would updating be as simple as just doing a "git pull"  then restarting nginx and gitlab ?

Thanks in advance.  And I do apologize for the novice gitlab experience.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded from 6.0.0-ee to 6.2.0-ee using the very detailed instructions at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-6.2.md

It went suspiciously smooth.    But now projects that were returing 404s now return a list of branches.

Comment: This solves the problem. But the link provided is broken. Use this one instead: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-6.4.md

Comment: Yeah, the link is broken again. Find your upgrade variant here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/update

Answer (score 1):

Can you please run: `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`

And tell me if you see any red checks?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Running that command seemed okay.  No checks in red, just a few in purple due to empty repositories.